# Inequality resulting from the algebra of summation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

I am sorry for the lack of specificity in the title.
I am having a hard time comprehending a portion of proof that simply asserts an inequality, where I fail to see why that statement should hold true.

To give bit of context.
Let $\gamma$ denote an $N\times{1}$ column vector such that $\gamma\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
Moreover, $\varepsilon$ is a $T\times{N}$ random matrix such that for a sample space $\Omega$ it follows that $\varepsilon:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^{T\times{N}}$. I
suppose, however, that the random nature of $\varepsilon$ has no implications for my question. So $\varepsilon$ might be thought of as a simple real $T\times{N}$ matrix.

Starting from

$$N^{-2}T^{-1}\,\,\gamma^\prime\varepsilon^\prime\varepsilon^{\phantom{\prime}}\gamma\,=\,N^{-2}T^{-1}\,\,\sum_j\sum_i\sum_t\,\gamma_j\,\gamma_i\,\varepsilon_{jt}\,\varepsilon_{it}$$
it follows by distributivity that.
$$N^{-2}T^{-1}\,\,\gamma^\prime\varepsilon^\prime\varepsilon^{\phantom{\prime}}\gamma\,=\,N^{-2}\,\,\sum_j\sum_i\,\gamma_j\,\gamma_i\,\left[T^{-1}\sum_t\,\varepsilon_{jt}\,\varepsilon_{it}\right]$$
So far that's absolutely fine. I am struggling with the next part:
$$N^{-2}\,\,\sum_j\sum_i\,\gamma_j\,\gamma_i\,\left[T^{-1}\sum_t\,\varepsilon_{jt}\,\varepsilon_{it}\right]\leq\left[N^{-2}\,\,\sum_j\sum_i\,\gamma^2_j\,\gamma^2_i\,\right]^{1/2}\times\,\left[N^{-2}\,\,\sum_j\sum_i\,\Big(T^{-1}\sum_t\,\varepsilon_{jt}\,\varepsilon_{it}\Big)^2\,\right]^{1/2}$$

I might be at a loss here, but how do I see that this statement is true. The prove moves on the consider the supremum of the above expression over all $\,\gamma:N^{-1}\gamma^\prime\gamma=1\,$. But - according to the proof - the statement above should hold without any restrictions being placed on $\gamma$.

I feel that I could easily construct scenarios where e.g.
$$\sum_j\sum_i\,\gamma_j\,\gamma_i>\left[\sum_j\sum_i\,\gamma^2_j\,\gamma^2_i\,\right]^{1/2}.$$

Thank you so very much for taking time.

Best wishes,
Jon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, cancel the factor $N^{-2}T^{-1}$ from both sides, to make things easier to read.

Let $K$ be the set of ordered pairs $(j, i)$ ($1 \leqslant j, i \leqslant n$). For $k = (j, i) \in K$, write:
\begin{align*}
x_k & = \gamma_j\gamma_i, \\
y_k & = \sum_t\,\varepsilon_{jt}\,\varepsilon_{it}.
\end{align*}

The inequality now reads:
$$
\sum_{k \in K}x_ky_k \leqslant \left[\sum_{k \in K}x_k^2\right]^{1/2}\left[\sum_{k \in K}y_k^2\right]^{1/2},
$$
which is an instance of the [Cauchy–Schwarz inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Schwarz_inequality), with a slightly unusual index set, $K$.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was definitely at a loss there.